# Fabricjs JSON error when it going to loadFromDatalessJSON

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I use the object clipTo to attach image to shape object, now when I save the canvas to JSON and store the data, it's working fine. Now when I load the JSON it give an error that this variable is undefined.

http://jsfiddle.net/efmbrm4v/2/

```
var clippingRect = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 100,
    top: 100,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    fill: 'transparent',
    opacity: 1
});
canvas.add(clippingRect);



var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(img, {
    width: instanceWidth,
    height: instanceHeight,
    top: (canvas.getHeight() / 2 - instanceHeight / 2),
    left: (canvas.getWidth() / 2 - instanceWidth / 2),
    originX: 'left',
    originY: 'top'
});
canvas.add(imgInstance);
imgInstance.clipTo = function(ctx) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);

    clippingRect.render(ctx); This part causing the error of undefined variable

    ctx.restore();
}
```

> **clippingRect.render(ctx);** This part causing the error of undefined variable.

Comment: No, that is why I'm posting it. Im runout of idea how to resolve it. I think you might have brilliant idea there? I'm just new to Fabricjs. @ℊααnd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is causing due to variable scoping. Since the code is running on window onload event, it loses reference for the rectangle­ (clippingRect) object and that­*'s* why it­*'s* throwing an error.

To make this work properly (on JSFiddle), you need to change the `LOAD TYPE` to `No wrap - in <body>`.

and, when working with your real project, place the script *(JS code)* before closing `<body>` tag.

**ᴡᴏʀᴋɪɴɢ ᴇxᴀᴍᴘʟᴇ ⧩**

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var c = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var clippingRect = new fabric.Rect({
   left: 50,
   top: 50,
   width: 100,
   height: 100,
   fill: 'transparent',
   opacity: 1
});

fabric.Image.fromURL('http://fabricjs.com/assets/pug_small.jpg', function(img) {
   img.set({
      left: 25,
      top: 25,
      width: 150,
      height: 150
   });
   canvas.add(img).setActiveObject(img);
   
   img.clipTo = function(ctx) {
      ctx.save();
      ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
      clippingRect.render(ctx);
      ctx.restore();
   }
   canvas.renderAll();
   
   var json = canvas.toJSON();
   c.loadFromJSON(json, c.renderAll.bind(c));
   c.renderAll();
});
```

```css
body{display:flex}canvas{border:1px solid #ccc}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.4.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<canvas id="c" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

also, on **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7sb5vkqd/)**

Comment: Still not working, the fabricjs lib is loaded on the header while the script is on the footer already. I load the plugin through jquery document ready.

Comment: don't load using jquery. just put your script in the footer and that'll do it.

Comment: Its a jQuery plugin. So I need to put it inside jquery document ready.

Comment: I'm building a plugin from the scratch uses jQuery and uses fabricjs for canvas.

Comment: hm. this should work if you just put it before closing the body tag (w/o putting inside jquery document ready)